# error C2057: expected constant expression

Tags: c++, c, signal-processing, c99

Doing some AudioDSP in VC++ 2012 and am having problems with allocating memory for the buffer

```
int size = input.getSize();
float buf[size];
```

At compile I get the error "error C2057: expected constant expression" Looks like the code works in C99 just not C++. Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 2):

That is because C99 supports variable length arrays, whilst C++ does not (at least, not C++98, nor C++11). Here are some workarounds:

- Refactor your code to use a `std::vector` or any suitable container. If possible, this would be the preferred method.
- Find a compiler that supports VLAs as an extension (for example, GCC with the option `-std=c++gnu98` or `-std=gnu++11`).

Anyway, if you don't have that much code to refactor, please try to change your code to use a standard container instead of a VLA.